# How would you write a function to create a linked list?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a function that would create a linked list, here is my attempt, I would appreciate if anyone could tell me if this is correct or not.

The logic is as follows:

- Take in a starting node, the created linked list will be connected to this node
- Create all the nodes that need to be created and store their memory addresses in a vector
- Loop through the vector linking together all of the nodes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:;
    int value;
    node *next;

    node():value(0),next(NULL){};
    
};

void CreateList(node& starting_node, int number_of_nodes_to_create){



    // Keep track of all the nodes addresses that need to be created

    vector <node*> nodes = {};
    // Create the nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_nodes_to_create;i++){
        node *temp = new node;
        nodes.push_back(temp);
    }

    // Attach the first created node to the starting node
    starting_node.next = nodes[0];

    // We now have all the new nodes, now we just need to link them all up with pointers

    

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size()-1;i++){

        nodes[i] ->next = nodes[i+1];

    }



}
```

I am very much a beginner, all criticism is welcome!

Comment: Firs write a function that inserts an item into a linked list, test the stuffing out of this function so that you know it works, and then call the  insert function for every item you want created. Consider making a linked list class to manage all of the book-keeping for the list.

Comment: @user15032639 I wonder who invents such silly assignments.

Comment: Turn up the warning level on your compiler. If you use `g++` or `clang++`, add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors`

Comment: In order to figure out what the insert function needs to look like, I recommend drawing pictures. Draw the empty list. Draw each step as you add an item to the empty list, making certain that all of the links are consistent at all times. Then draw all the steps as you add a second item. And then a third. Use the drawings as the basis for the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did! For myself.

Comment: @user15032639 Why not to write a function that inserts nodes in a singly-linked list without using a vector?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `vector` at all.  Your function can be simplified to something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int value;
    node *next;

    node() : value(0), next(NULL) {}
};

void CreateList(node* &starting_node, int number_of_nodes_to_create){

    // if the list already exists, find the end of it...
    node **n = &starting_node;
    while (*n) {
        n = &((*n)->next);
    }

    // Create the nodes
    while (number_of_nodes_to_create > 0) {
        *n = new node;
        n = &((*n)->next);
        --number_of_nodes_to_create;
    }
}

void DestroyList(node *starting_node) {
    while (starting_node) {
        node *n = starting_node->next;
        delete starting_node;
        starting_node = n;
    }
}

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;
    CreateList(head, 5);
    ...
    DestroyList(head);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/3bEraD)

Though, it is not usual for a list creation to take an existing node as input.  Usually the creation should create the list and then return the 1st (head) node, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    int value;
    node *next;

    node() : value(0), next(NULL) {}
};

node* CreateList(int number_of_nodes_to_create){
    node *head = NULL, **n = &head;
    while (number_of_nodes_to_create > 0) {
        *n = new node;
        n = &((*n)->next);
        --number_of_nodes_to_create;
    }
    return head;
}

void DestroyList(node *head) {
    while (head) {
        node *n = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = n;
    }
}

int main() {
    node* head = CreateList(5);
    ...
    DestroyList(head);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/lRrVVJ)